# Sending / Reading Instagram Direct Messages using Facebook app account or any other means

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have got a question if someone could help me: 
I want my app to receive webhook notifications for Instagram Direct messages using GraphAPI.

I tried using "instagram_manage_messages" permission (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/instagram_manage_messages) but doesn't work.
Could someone please help how can I read and write messages.

Related issue on Facebook community: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/248857906358385/

Answer (score 2):

The facebook team are announcing that there are updates to the Messenger API to support Instagram messaging, giving businesses new tools to manage their customer communications on Instagram at scale. The new API features enable businesses to integrate Instagram messaging with their preferred business applications and workflows; helping drive more meaningful conversations, increase customer satisfaction and grow sales. The updated API is currently in beta with a limited number of developer partners and businesses.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2020/10/19/messenger-api-to-support-Instagram/

Comment: Please add some information from the link to your answer, as link only answers are prone to being useless in the future as links inevitably get broken

Comment: **i am looking at the documentation, but i cannot seem to find anything about whether or not i will be able to read DMs with the API?** i was hoping to build myself a tool to scan DMs for leads and then collect and aggregate the leads information